# How to write a CSV without headers

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a file that looks like this:

```
milk 7,dark 0,white 0,sugar free 1
milk 0,dark 3,white 0,sugar free 0
milk 0,dark 3,white 0,sugar free 5
milk 0,dark 1,white 5,sugar free 3
```

There are no headers in that CSV. However, every time I open this file in a program like `Numbers`, it looks like this:

[image]

Is this a problem with how I wrote data to the CSV or a problem with the CSV program... it probably is because the choice of delimiter is wrong.

My code when writing looks like this:

```
def self.write(output_path:, data:, write_headers: false)
    CSV.open(output_path, "w", write_headers: write_headers) do |csv|
      data.each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
```

What does the `write_headers` part even do?

Comment: In your `Numbers` program, there should be an option like `No Headers`, I don't think it's necessary to add blank values to the first row just to imitate a header row. But the cell value format seems wrong.. if `milk`, `dark`, `white`, and `sugar free` are supposed to be headers, they shouldn't be in each cell.. if they are correct cell values, then the `Numbers` program is wrongly using the blank space as delimiter rather than the comma. You can change that inside `Numbers` itself

Comment: They are supposed to be in the cell actually. I know it's strange but that's what the requirement asked for.

Comment: What is write_headers supposed to be doing in `CSV.open`?

Comment: what if you get rid of the `write_headers: write_headers` in `CSV.open` ?

Comment: You can see the explanation on [this page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-write_headers-3F)

Comment: @Jwan622 : Looking at the raw CSV file which you posted, it is perfectly fine. If you would create it manually, you would write it exactly the same, wouldn't you? Hence, the question has nothing to do with Ruby, and I suggest to remove the _ruby_ tag.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a problem with how I wrote data to the CSV or a problem with the CSV program... it probably is because the choice of delimiter is wrong.

Your CSV data is perfectly fine. CSV is only loosely standardized and there's no concept of marking a header row as such within the file. It cannot be distinguished from any other row, syntax-wise.

> What does the `write_headers` part even do?

It's used together with `headers`. From the docs for [`CSV.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

> **`:write_headers`**
>   When `true` and `:headers` is set, a header row will be added to the output.

Example:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.generate(headers: %w[a b c], write_headers: true) do |csv|
  csv << [1, 2, 3]
  csv << [4, 5, 6]
end
#=> "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n"
```

as opposed to:

```
CSV.generate(headers: %w[a b c], write_headers: false) do |csv|
  csv << [1, 2, 3]
  csv << [4, 5, 6]
end
#=> "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

`write_headers` will add a header row to the output when it's set true. I think setting `headers: false` in your options hash will fix your issue (when it's set true, it treats the first line of the CSV as headers)

Comment: Does it make any difference? Being a _header_ is a logical concept, i.e. the way we interpret the first row. Imagine a CSV file where each field in each row contains a different English word. By just looking at it, there is no way  to tell, whether the first line is meant to be a header or raw data. Look at the raw CSV file presented by the OP: It looks perfectly fine. There is nothing in it which would suggest that the first line should be considered as a header.